# How can I insert ads to web page?

Tags: javascript, ads

I am trying to insert ads on my web page, so I inserted the following code into my page.

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-5013858870378628" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<div class="adver">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block; width: 50%;"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-5013858870378628"
         data-ad-slot="9539779295"
         data-ad-format="auto"
         data-full-width-responsive="false"></ins>
    <script>
         adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
                  
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block; width: 50%;"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-5013858870378628"
         data-ad-slot="9539779295"
         data-ad-format="auto"
         data-full-width-responsive="false"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

but I cannot see any ads.

When I check it with the Inspection Tools, I can see following code on the `iframe` tag:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <script>window.top.postMessage('{"msg_type":"resize-me","key_value":[{"key":"r_nh","value":"0"},{"key":"qid","value":"CIGkz6yLq_ACFetGkQUdNPUBaw"}],"googMsgType":"sth"}', '*');</script>
             <script>window.top.postMessage('{"msg_type":"adsense-labs","key_value":[{"key":"settings","value":"[\\\"ca-pub-5013858870378628\\\"]"}],"googMsgType":"sth"}', '*');</script> 
        </head>
     </html>
```

What is my fault?

Page URL: https://gamehome.jp/product/test10/

Comment: Adblocker? I get `GET https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: you mean adblocker extension of browser? I didn't use Adblocker

Comment: Look in the console and network tab for error

Comment: I get this in Safari: `TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0`

Comment: [Possible solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=tagError:+adsbygoogle.push()+error:+No+slot+size+for+availableWidth%3D0+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even you have successfully pushed ads, if they don't accept your request.
in other words, if they think your site is not useful or will not have enough visitor, they will not accept it and do not show any ads.
that's why you need to make your site looks beautiful and user friendly.
and never include unformal contents.

Comment: I know that. but still not showing.